# Copy column data into rows below in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and need to have some database management. I have a large dataset in CSV and the column name repeats after a certain column. I need to copy that column set below the end of rows of the first set. As shown in the image below, I want to cut and paste the dataset for each ID { 03]01]17, 03]01]16, 03]01]15 and so on...I have attached here the sample data and required format. [image: Sample format] [image: Required format]

```
,Day,Time,Q,V,N,Unnamed: 5,Q.1,V.1,N.1,Unnamed: 9,Q.2,V.2,N.2,Unnamed: 13,Q.3,V.3,N.3
0,,,03]01]17,,,,03]01]16,,,,03]01]15,,,,03]01]14,,
1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,2019N11,00:00-00:05,48,80.2,2.3,,65,78.8,2.8,,67,78.6,2.9, ,71,84.3,2.6
3,,00:05-00:10,87,75.1,4.2,,102,77.2,4.8,,98,76.2,4.7, ,94,83.9,4.4
4,,00:10-00:15,56,78.0,2.2,,62,81.2,2.3,,66,77.2,2.7, ,70,81.3,2.6
5,,00:15-00:20,62,73.6,2.7,,79,76.9,3.3,,82,74.5,3.5, ,78,84.1,2.8
6,,00:20-00:25,69,75.6,3.0,,84,77.4,3.6,,81,75.4,3.5, ,81,83.0,3.2
7,,00:25-00:30,65,76.0,2.6,,69,77.2,2.7,,75,76.1,3.2, ,72,84.4,2.7
8,,00:30-00:35,62,77.9,2.6,,77,79.4,3.2,,82,77.9,3.4, ,83,86.1,3.1
9,,00:35-00:40,63,80.0,2.2,,82,76.6,3.2,,79,78.7,3.2, ,74,86.0,2.6
10,,00:40-00:45,52,79.5,2.0,,66,81.2,2.2,,69,78.9,2.5, ,74,85.0,2.6
11,,00:45-00:50,59,73.9,2.6,,73,78.9,2.9,,76,76.7,3.0, ,73,84.3,2.6
12,,00:50-00:55,67,77.4,2.8,,89,78.0,3.4,,87,74.9,3.4, ,90,82.6,3.1
13,,00:55-01:00,49,74.2,1.9,,75,76.6,2.8,,78,73.5,3.0, ,75,82.9,2.6

dfsample = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
dfsample

##Required_format

,ID,Day,Time,Q,V,N
0,03]01]17,2019N11,00:00-00:05,48,80.2,2.3
1,,,00:05-00:10,87,75.1,4.2
2,,,00:10-00:15,56,78.0,2.2
3,,,00:15-00:20,62,73.6,2.7
4,,,00:20-00:25,69,75.6,3.0
5,,,00:25-00:30,65,76.0,2.6
6,,,00:30-00:35,62,77.9,2.6
7,,,00:35-00:40,63,80.0,2.2
8,,,00:40-00:45,52,79.5,2.0
9,,,00:45-00:50,59,73.9,2.6
10,,,00:50-00:55,67,77.4,2.8
11,,,00:55-01:00,49,74.2,1.9
12,03]01]16,2019N11,00:00-00:05,65,78.8,2.8
13,,,00:05-00:10,102,77.2,4.8
14,,,00:10-00:15,62,81.2,2.3
15,,,00:15-00:20,79,76.9,3.3
16,,,00:20-00:25,84,77.4,3.6
17,,,00:25-00:30,69,77.2,2.7
18,,,00:30-00:35,77,79.4,3.2
19,,,00:35-00:40,82,76.6,3.2
20,,,00:40-00:45,66,81.2,2.2
21,,,00:45-00:50,73,78.9,2.9
22,,,00:50-00:55,89,78.0,3.4
23,,,00:55-01:00,75,76.6,2.8
24,03]01]15,2019N11,00:00-00:05,67,78.6,2.9
25,,,00:05-00:10,98,76.2,4.7
26,,,00:10-00:15,66,77.2,2.7
27,,,00:15-00:20,82,74.5,3.5
28,,,00:20-00:25,81,75.4,3.5
29,,,00:25-00:30,75,76.1,3.2
30,,,00:30-00:35,82,77.9,3.4
31,,,00:35-00:40,79,78.7,3.2
32,,,00:40-00:45,69,78.9,2.5
33,,,00:45-00:50,76,76.7,3.0
34,,,00:50-00:55,87,74.9,3.4
35,,,00:55-01:00,78,73.5,3.0
36,03]01]14,2019N11,00:00-00:05,71,84.3,2.6
37,,,00:05-00:10,94,83.9,4.4
38,,,00:10-00:15,70,81.3,2.6
39,,,00:15-00:20,78,84.1,2.8
40,,,00:20-00:25,81,83.0,3.2
41,,,00:25-00:30,72,84.4,2.7
42,,,00:30-00:35,83,86.1,3.1
43,,,00:35-00:40,74,86.0,2.6
44,,,00:40-00:45,74,85.0,2.6
45,,,00:45-00:50,73,84.3,2.6
46,,,00:50-00:55,90,82.6,3.1
47,,,00:55-01:00,75,82.9,2.6

dfrequired = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
dfrequired
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the content of your csv file, please?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)

DAY = df.iloc[2, 0]
ID = df.iloc[0, 2]
TIME = df.iloc[2:, 1]

result_df = pd.DataFrame()
i = 0
for n in range(2, df.shape[1], 4):
    if i==0:
        first_col = n
        last_col = n+3
        temp_df = df.iloc[:, first_col:last_col]
        temp_df = temp_df.iloc[2:, :]
        temp_df.insert(0, 'ID', np.nan)
        temp_df.iloc[0, 0] = ID
        temp_df.insert(1, 'Day', np.nan)
        temp_df.iloc[0, 1] = DAY
        temp_df.insert(2, 'Time', np.nan)
        temp_df.iloc[:, 2] = TIME
        result_df = result_df.append(temp_df)
        i += 1
    else:
        first_col = n
        last_col = n+3
        temp_df = df.iloc[:, first_col:last_col]
        ID = temp_df.iloc[0, 0]
        temp_df = temp_df.iloc[2:, :]
        temp_df.insert(0, 'ID', np.nan)
        temp_df.iloc[0, 0] = ID
        temp_df.insert(1, 'Day', np.nan)
        temp_df.iloc[0, 1] = DAY
        temp_df.insert(2, 'Time', np.nan)
        temp_df.iloc[:, 2] = TIME
        temp_df.columns = result_df.columns
        result_df = result_df.append(temp_df)
    
result_df = result_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, there we go. First of all, I created a random sample file that looks just like yours:

[image]

(link here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/121li6T5OfSlZ12-HrxyP_Thd4NIuu1jK/view?usp=sharing)

Then, I uploaded it as a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('database.csv')
```

output:
[image]

My approach was to create lists and group them as a new dataframe:

```
Q_index   = [i for i in range(len(df.columns)) if 'Q' in df.columns[i]]
id_list   = [i for sub_list in [[id]+list(np.ones(11)*np.nan) for id in df.iloc[0].dropna()] for i in sub_list]
day_list  = df.loc[2,'Day']
time_list = (df['Time'][2:]).tolist()*len(Q_index)
Q_list    = [i for sub_list in [df.iloc[2:,i].tolist()   for i in Q_index] for i in sub_list]
V_list    = [i for sub_list in [df.iloc[2:,i+1].tolist() for i in Q_index] for i in sub_list]
N_list    = [i for sub_list in [df.iloc[2:,i+2].tolist() for i in Q_index] for i in sub_list]

result_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID'  :id_list,
                          'Day' :day_list,
                          'Time':time_list,
                          'Q'   :Q_list,
                          'V'   :V_list,
                          'N'   :N_list}).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Output:

result_df

```
         ID     Day        Time      Q      V     N
0   3]01]17 2019N11 00:00-00:05   91.9   70.0   3.0
1   3]01]17 2019N11 00:05-00:10   92.7   80.1   4.0
2   3]01]17 2019N11 00:10-00:15   68.3   86.8   3.2
3   3]01]17 2019N11 00:15-00:20   40.2   74.5   4.4
4   3]01]17 2019N11 00:20-00:25   81.4   74.3   3.3
5   3]01]17 2019N11 00:25-00:30   45.2   85.0   4.8
6   3]01]17 2019N11 00:30-00:35   92.3   82.3   3.6
7   3]01]17 2019N11 00:35-00:40   78.7   81.2   3.0
8   3]01]17 2019N11 00:40-00:45   88.8   86.2   2.0
9   3]01]17 2019N11 00:45-00:50   75.4   79.9   4.5
10  3]01]17 2019N11 00:50-00:55   53.0   73.6   3.2
11  3]01]17 2019N11 00:55-01:00   58.9   82.7   4.4
12  3]01]16 2019N11 00:00-00:05   62.9   77.1   3.1
13  3]01]16 2019N11 00:05-00:10   52.2   78.7   2.0
14  3]01]16 2019N11 00:10-00:15   52.0   79.0   4.7
15  3]01]16 2019N11 00:15-00:20   77.6   85.3   4.4
16  3]01]16 2019N11 00:20-00:25   57.8   84.0   5;0
17  3]01]16 2019N11 00:25-00:30   47.9   77.0   3.1
18  3]01]16 2019N11 00:30-00:35   62.4   84.5   3.2
19  3]01]16 2019N11 00:35-00:40   84.5   83.4   5.0
20  3]01]16 2019N11 00:40-00:45   56.6   88.6   2.5
21  3]01]16 2019N11 00:45-00:50   47.9   84.7   4.8
22  3]01]16 2019N11 00:50-00:55   92.5   77.8   3.7
23  3]01]16 2019N11 00:55-01:00   60.6   75.0   4.5
24  3]01]15 2019N11 00:00-00:05   51.8   86.3   4.4
25  3]01]15 2019N11 00:05-00:10   52.9   83.6   5.0
26  3]01]15 2019N11 00:10-00:15   52.5   85.4   3.4
27  3]01]15 2019N11 00:15-00:20   46.1   81.2   2.3
28  3]01]15 2019N11 00:20-00:25   65.1   70.9   4.7
29  3]01]15 2019N11 00:25-00:30   65.2   77.6   2.6
30  3]01]15 2019N11 00:30-00:35   67.1   84.2   4.1
31  3]01]15 2019N11 00:35-00:40   42.2   82.2   3.3
32  3]01]15 2019N11 00:40-00:45   71.5   79.8   2.4
33  3]01]15 2019N11 00:45-00:50   65.1   72.3   2.9
34  3]01]15 2019N11 00:50-00:55   86.0   80.3   3.9
35  3]01]15 2019N11 00:55-01:00   92.8   85.9   4.1
36  3]01]14 2019N11 00:00-00:05   53.2   82.4   3.1
37  3]01]14 2019N11 00:05-00:10   98.0   76.0   3.5
38  3]01]14 2019N11 00:10-00:15   58.9   88.3   4.4
39  3]01]14 2019N11 00:15-00:20   95.3   85.1   3.2
40  3]01]14 2019N11 00:20-00:25   45.7   74.0   3.5
41  3]01]14 2019N11 00:25-00:30   48.6   89.7   4.8
42  3]01]14 2019N11 00:30-00:35   94.6   79.5   2.1
43  3]01]14 2019N11 00:35-00:40   71.8   73.0   3.8
44  3]01]14 2019N11 00:40-00:45   92.5   83.1   2.0
45  3]01]14 2019N11 00:45-00:50   70.3   79.4   4.2
46  3]01]14 2019N11 00:50-00:55   83.6   82.6   2.8
47  3]01]14 2019N11 00:55-01:00   56.2   89.1   2.6
```

Comment: Thanks, I slove my problem with the help of this solution